# How to check progress of a script running in R Studio?

Tags: rstudio

I am running a script in R Studio that I expect takes pretty long, how can I see if the script is still running though, as opposed to R Studio crashing? Right now R Studio just has that '+' sign in console, so I think that means it's still running.